# Page numbers in multipage \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

I am using memoir class; 
`\mainmatter` switches numbering to roman AND lower page centered number which is good, but in a multiple page table of contents only page one is numbered that way, next pages have their numbers in roman BUT in running head!

Is it possible to have all pages numbered bottom center roman in the table of contents? (without affecting other pages, i.e. like in Prologue etc.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright, oldfontcommands, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\begin{document}%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frontmatter     
%%%%%%%%%% STYLES%%%%%%%%
\chapterstyle{dash}
\setsecheadstyle{\scshape\raggedright}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}

\pagestyle{companion}

\setsecheadstyle{\scshape\large\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\scshape\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\itshape\raggedright}
\setparaheadstyle{\scshape \raggedright}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{Prologue}


\chapter{Thanks}
Thanks
\newpage        
\tableofcontents     
\mainmatter              
\chapter{zz}
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\chapter{zz}
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 

\end{document}
```

Comment: having all pages numbered would be the default, so you need to show what code you are using to stop that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

This `memoir` document has a three page table of contents with numbers i,ii,iii

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\section{ff}bbb
\section{ff}bbb


\mainmatter

\chapter{zz}
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\chapter{zz}
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks,how come mine has a number only on first page????

Comment: @Fred_O: We could answer that if you would shown us some of your code, but ... alas, there is none ;-)

Comment: @Fred_O latex is a programming language, it just follows the instructions you gave it.

Comment: ok, a better look at it and I found that pages were actually numbered but with the type of running head I didin't want...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want running heads in the table of contents, then typeset it under `\pagestyle{plain}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright, oldfontcommands, 11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\begin{document}%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%
\frontmatter     
%%%%%%%%%% STYLES%%%%%%%%
\chapterstyle{dash}
\setsecheadstyle{\scshape\raggedright}
\setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}

\pagestyle{companion}

\setsecheadstyle{\scshape\large\raggedright}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\scshape\raggedright}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\itshape\raggedright}
\setparaheadstyle{\scshape \raggedright}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapter{Prologue}


\chapter{Thanks}
Thanks
\newpage

{\pagestyle{plain}\tableofcontents\relax\clearpage}

\mainmatter              
\chapter{zz}
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\chapter{zz}
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 
\section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb \section{aa}bbb 

\end{document}
```

[image]